Using ptrace to get arguments and return value of child's system calls
I'm trying to better understand how strace works by trying to write a much simplified version of strace, but I'm having difficulty getting the correct return value of system calls. Could someone please point out my error or other things to try?
The parent is basically in a loop that calls waitpid(...) twice, once for syscall
entry and once for exit. Here's the shell of my code. My exit code is wrong.
    while (1) {
      waitpid (child_pid, &status, 0);
      if (WIFSTOPPED (status)) {
        if (ptrace (PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs) == 0) {
          syscall_num = regs.orig_rax;
          get_syscall_info (syscall_num, child_pid, &regs, buff);
          printf("%s", buff);
        }
        ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
      } /* other else clauses for WIFEXITED etc. */

      // system call return
      waitpid (child_pid, &status, 0);
      if (WIFSTOPPED (status)) {
        if (ptrace (PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs) == 0) {
          exit_code = regs.rax;
          printf (" -> %llu\n", regs.rax);
        }
        ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
      } /* other else clauses for WIFEXITED etc. */
    }

My output is the following:
lseek(syscall=8) -> 18446744073709551578
fstat(syscall=5) -> 18446744073709551578
write(syscall=1) -> 18446744073709551578
close(syscall=3) -> 18446744073709551578
close(syscall=3) -> 18446744073709551578
close(syscall=3) -> 18446744073709551578

